# Azure Logic Apps - Conditions. Is it possible to check for amount of chars in the string response? (And more..)

Tags: azure, conditional-statements, azure-logic-apps

I am using a Condition Action in my Azure LogicApps.
Currently I am only checking if "PersonNr" ends with "0000".
This is how it looks:
[image]

The value I get is a 12 digit birth number, SSN. For example: 199206243767
That is yyyyDDmmxxxx.

I want a condition that checks if the value I receive has a string with 12 characters. If it's less than 12 then it's wrong and I do not want it but there does not seem to be any option for this.
Using the length() expression does not work either.

What's more.. I would also like to check if all the characters if the 12char string value is only 0-9. If there are any letters I do not want it.

I tried adding "length()" expression -- Is equal to -- "12" and also an expression that says string(12)
I thought it would check if the value i received has 12 characters but instead this error:
"'The template language function 'length' expects one parameter: an array or a string the length of which is returned. The function was invoked with '0' parameters. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#length for usage details.'."

Comment: Show us your attempt with length(), I think it’s clear that you’re not quite across how to use expressions.

Comment: Previously I had it set as "length(outputs('Compose')?['persorgnr'])"
...
After reading your comment I finally realized why it was not working for me.
I've now changed it to length(items('For_each_ResultSet')?['persorgnr']) and "is equal to" and "12" and now it actually works...

12 turns into true and 13 into false.

Been stuck for almost two days and I just needed your comment to help me rethink what I had done. Thank you for that and I'm sorry for asking such an easy question.
Have a good one!

Comment: Ok, and your checking for all numbers requirement? Still need that?

Comment: If such a thing is possible it would be great.
I dont even know where to start since the value I get is a string so the only allowed characters should be 0-9.

Any advice on how to do it would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if your string is a number, you can use `isInt()` or `isFloat()`.  For your situation, `isInt()` is better but your number is too large for that so you need to use `isFloat()`.

[image: IsNumber]

This is the expression ...

```
isFloat(variables('Numbers String'))
```

... and this is the result ...

[image: IsNumber]

... you can then do what you need from there, you can even use that expression directly within a condition.

Comment: This worked out great

Made sure if it worked for me by giving it a value with letters and numbers and another with only numbers and it works as it should!

Used it in my condition where I put the "isFloat" expression - Equals to - True

Thanks a lot Skin, you made my day a lot easier :)

Answer (score 0):

My issue was a simple one and I've now solved it, thanks to "Skin" for helping me rethink.

When trying to add a length() expression I used the value of the compose action above. What I needed to do was to go step further and check it from the current for each loop values.

Originally I had this expression:
"length(outputs('Compose')?['persorgnr'])"

It resulted in an error.

The expression that worked was this:
length(items('For_each_ResultSet')?['persorgnr'])

Thanks again to Skin for replying, it helped me realize my error.